# Lua: end MPV at a time

Tags: lua, mpv

Using [MPV](https://mpv.io) I want a Lua script to end playback of a stream at the end of a show but my script does nothing at the time I set it to.

```
curtime = os.date("!%H:%M:%S")
endtime = "00:30:00"

if ( curtime == endtime )
then mp.command("quit")
end
```

Comment: Share the full code

Comment: Is the intent for the curtime to be UTC? so your stream ends at 12:30 am UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your code to evaluate the epoch time, this way you can evaluate time as a numeric value.

```
endtime = endtime or os.time() + 3600 -- add the expected stream duration in seconds.
curtime = os.time()

if (curtime >= endtime) then
    mp.command("quit")
end
```

Your example has only 1 second in time where the if statement is true. While 1 second is a long time for a computer, it is possible to miss a window defined so absolutely. If your code has points where it may sleep or wait for a long time you can miss the window from that alone.

Here in my example the stream is set to end 1 hour after the first time this section of code is run, this is represented by the 3600 seconds i added to os.time().

Once the current time is equal to **or greater than** that increase of 3600 seconds the if statement condition will be true and the quit command should be sent.